# Rollover Image to Text with Transparent Background

Tags: javascript, html, css

I haven't worked much with Javascript, but I have a rough idea of how to make an image rollover to another image. I'm trying to make an image that, when moused over, will become a transparent background to a block of text that will occupy the space the image occupied. I've seen lots of tutorials but nothing matching quite that.

Also: is there any way to format this text with css or otherwise? (Like adding padding, line breaks, etc.)

Any help or links to a site where I can figure it out would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Do you want the background image to become completely transparent or translucent?

Comment: Translucent, I suppose. My mistake. I essentially want to lower its opacity and slap text in front of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/asifrc/Spres/) is a pure css implementation that changes the opacity of an image placed in front of the text on hover. To do this I used put the text and image containers both within a container div and set `position: absolute` so that they overlap. I then change the opacity of the image by using the `:hover` selector. Since the text is behind the image, it can't be selected. Let me know if this what your looking for, and specify what you would like differently if it isn't :)

Comment: This works fantastically, and exactly as I needed it to. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the text to stay after the mouseover, you could use javascript to toggle a class on the rollover and add some text.  E.g., put an image as the background to a div with some class (e.g., `class="solid-image"`). When you want to change the element, just change the class (e.g., with `myElement.className="translucent-image"`) and then you can either have text that was previously invisible or you can add text to the div (so long as it doesn't have children) by using the `textContent` or `innerText` element. E.g.:

```
text = "textContent" in document ? "textContent" : "innerText";
myDomElement[text] = "My text here";
```

And then add an event listener for the appropriate events.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks very much! I think I'll go with the all CSS implementation mentioned above, but this answered my original question as well. Thanks again!